# OpenAI Gym Manual Play function automatically presses key

Tags: python, openai-gym

```
import gym
from gym.utils import play
play.play(gym.make('MountainCar-v0', render_mode='rgb_array').env, zoom=1,  keys_to_action={"0":0, "2":2, "1":1})
```

The above code is all that is needed to play MountainCar manually.

The controls are as follows:

0 = nothing

1 = left

2 = right

However when I run the code, if I'm not pressing anything, the car automatically goes to the left as if the "1" key on the keyboard is being pressed down.

I've tried searching through the docs for a solution but no luck.
https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/utils/play.py

Answer (score 1):

```
import gym
from gym.utils import play
env = play.play(gym.make('MountainCar-v0', render_mode='rgb_array').env, zoom=1,  keys_to_action={"2":2, "1":0}, noop=1)
```

the noop sets the default action